# Access denied on deploy to 2012 R2 server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, robocopy

We have a 2012 R2 server that is outside our core. I'm able to RDP to this server using our build server credentials but I'm unable to Powershell or Robocopy code changes to this server. I'm also unable to create a mapped drive on the build server with the build server's credentials to this new DMZ server.  We are getting an 'Access Denied' error.  Is anyone able to shed light on this?

Comment: Are you able to create a remote PowerShell session to the server using the build server creds? Is that account a local admin, or is it whitelisted to run as a batch process or anything?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I am able to create a remote PowerShell session to stop/start the app pool for the site but that's as far as i can go.  The user is added to the Users group and Administrators group on the server.

Comment: I'm guessing the SMB ports are blocked via firewall or some such. Try `Test-NetConnection <DMZ Server> -Port 445` and see if the port is open from the build server.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I've checked and the port is indeed opened between the build server and the DMZ server.